# What is the difference between Entity and Persistent class?

Tags: hibernate, jpa, orm, entity, persistence

I am going through the [Hibernate Documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html_single/#mapping-types-entitiesvalues) where the author used the terms `persistent class` to refer to `entities`.

The author says, **Not all user-defined classes with a persistent state, however, are entities...**

I am unable to differentiate between the two. Please suggest.

Answer (score 2):

Hibernate [defines](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html_single/#persistent-classes) the persistent class as **any classes that can be persisted to the database.**

There are two types of persistent classes : **entity type** and **value type** . So entity is one type of the persistent class.

Entity type are those classes that are marked with `@Entity` while value type are those classes marked with `@Embeddable` or some basic Java type such as `String` , `Integer` , `Date` etc.

The main difference between them is that value type does not define their own life-cycle.They are "owned" by entity type which defines their life-cycle.

We create an entity type class which contains many value type classes.

Comment: I was editing some other thing. The answer got edited mistakenly. I reverted it back to the original. Sorry.